# Regex javascript code, but retaining middle text

Tags: javascript, regex, eclipse, find-replace

I am trying to redo all of our JavaScript code for a page and make it consistent.  I have a function that returns getElementById(Id) with just $ but there are a lot of document.form.elementID.value so I need to turn all of these into $("elementID").value

What would be the Regex to retain the ElementID when I am doing a mass replacement in Ecipse?  I will also need to add the quotes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tested in Eclipse:

Find

```
document.form.(\w+).value
```

Replace

```
\$\("$1"\)
```

Comment: Need to escape the first $ sign. Add a \ before the start. Updated answer.